# Load just one field from node

Tags: nodes

I have x nodes with field named "thefield". My script is checking "thefield" and if he does so the right value is updated.

How can i get from node just one field for check and didnt load full entity (node_load)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a db_query to find all nodes that that field appears on and then update them with a node_load here is the code:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT f.entity_id FROM {field_data_field_thefield} f');
foreach ($result as $record) {
    $node = node_load($record->entity_id);
    // update node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it programmatically or using views.

Using Views : Create a view page and under the fields section add the following fields:

Node id and the specific field you would like to update.

Update the filter condition as follows:
Node type = 'YOUR NODE TYPE'
AND
"Your required field" = NOT NULL

The output of this view will be the node ids of all those node which will be having a values assigned to the specific field.

If this didn't helped you, please let me know, will solve it in a different way

Thanks

Comment: Hi, im looking for programatical way. Becouse views object isnt good for performance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nid = 1;
$thefield = db_select('field_data_field_thefield', 'f');
  ->fields('f',array('entity_id'))
  ->condition('f.entity_id', $nid, '=');
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

if($thefield){
  Do Something...
}
```

You could use a db_query instead of db_select to make it even quicker

Comment: what mean 'f' parameter?

Comment: f is just an alias for the field table. I have just updated the name to better reflect how it will be stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update any field in node , then better to use `node_load()` function. 
Because if you use any custom **select** or **update** query then

- first thing you need to update it in all the tables (main and revision tables).
- Second thing, drupal events will not trigger that is attached with updation.

If you still want to do it manually by `db_select()` and `db_query()`

Hope it will help!

Comment: In my case, i need to check all nodes of one type just for one field, so its better for performance when i dont "build" full node, sure for write i will get full node

Comment: Then i don't see any other way than custom queries. But you check the fields easily but during updation you need to take care of all the conditions and pattern in which the data need to be wrtite in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The field API allows you to load/attach just one field in a list of entities with  [`field_attach_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7). This approach is field storage agnostic, invokes field-level hooks, and reads from the field cache if possible.